# Database for storing small amounts of data used in a java application

Tags: java, database

Iam developing a client/server app in java.
I need to store ids , passwords etc of all the users for login,document sharing and chat purposes.
I dont want to install any DBMS because i need only 1 or 2 tables with around a thousand entries.
Is there any way to do this??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Why not use the [JavaDb](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javadb/index.html) which comes with the JDK as standard ? You can run it in-JVM and persist to the file-system. It's a SQL database so if you're familiar witha RDBMS it should be straightforward to integrate.

Comment: Yes,Im familiar with rdbms.But i couldnt understand what Embedded database(javaDB) is and how to use it.Should the user have to install it??

Comment: No. You can just instantiate it as a normal class in your Java program

Comment: @BrianAgnew Well, as far as I know, it's NOT part of the JRE, which is what users will have installed on their systems, so you still need them to install a JDK...

Comment: @us2012 - Very interesting. Hadn't realised that. Thx for the clarification

Answer (score 2):

You can write the data to a local file on the server, and read it from there, but its hardly efficient.

Answer (score 2):

Check out [HSQLDB](http://hsqldb.org) or [H2 database](http://www.h2database.com/html/main.html). Both will fit your needs

Both have a rich set of SQL features, can run embedded or standalone and have a small memory footprint. Personally I prefer HSQLDB over H2 but not for a specific reason.